# Why did dnf info and dnf search initiate updates Fedora 38?

Tags: fedora

I was looking for a package and ran `dnf search` to see if I had it before installing from source and a bunch of system updates started. I killed the process, thought weird and ran `dnf info` to see if I could find some other info. That too started running updates though it kept asking repeatedly if I importing a `GPG key` for postgres (starting with 15 then 14 then 13) was ok.

I've never seen this happen before. Can anyone explain the gist of it and hopefully provide docs where I can read more. Is this standard behavior for `dnf`?

Here's a copy paste from the terminal window:

```
[nick@nicks-x1 project]$ dnf search valgrind
Copr repo for PyCharm owned by phracek                                                                                            33 kB/s |  45 kB     00:01    
Brave Browser - Beta                                                                                                              24 kB/s |  15 kB     00:00    
determining the fastest mirror (144 hosts).. done.                [            ===                                             ] ---  B/s |   0  B     --:-- ETA
Fedora 38 - x86_64                                                                                                               2.2 MB/s |  83 MB     00:37    
Fedora 38 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64                                                                                         773  B/s | 2.5 kB     00:03    
Fedora Modular 38 - x86_64                                                                                                       1.5 MB/s | 2.8 MB     00:01    
^CFedora 38 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'updates': Librepo was interrupted by a signal
[nick@nicks-x1 project]$ man dnf
[nick@nicks-x1 project]$ dnf info valgrind
Fedora 38 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                     2.2 MB/s |  32 MB     00:14    
Fedora Modular 38 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                             1.5 MB/s | 2.1 MB     00:01    
google-chrome                                                                                                                     13 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
pgadmin4                                                                                                                         427  B/s | 833  B     00:01    
pgadmin4                                                                                                                         3.8 MB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00    
Importing GPG key 0x210976F2:
```

Comment: It looks like it's updating the package lists from the enabled repositories, which has been standard behaviour for yum for a long time (forever?) (and so I'd expect the same for dnf). That will naturally involve adding the repository keys if you haven't done so before. I don't see it upgrading any packages in the output you show.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just switched from MacOS  to Linux my daily os and get confused from time to time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behaviour; `dnf` is [synchronizing its metadata](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#metadata-synchronization) from the configured repositories. It is not actually updating any of the packages on your system, only the information about packages available in repositories.

You don’t see this *every* time you run `dnf` because it caches this data and only updates it if it’s too old. The cache timeout is configured [using the `metadata_expire` entry](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html#metadata-expire-label) in `dnf.conf` (and in repository metadata), and is set to 48h by default.

You can avoid this with `dnf -C`; `dnf` will then operate using only its locally-cached metadata.